# Reading/Getting text in an Application window using VBscript

Tags: vbscript

I have automated an entry process using sendkeys and .appActivate.

The script has the option of setting the delay in seconds i.e how fast sendkeys sends the keystrokes to the application window. However, the window's time interval varies.

The text "ready" is displayed on the window (when the window is ready for the next entry). i want the script to read that "Ready" to sendkeys as against the static delay of the seconds.

please, if the question is not clear, i can explain further. Thanks

Comment: VBScript is not a very good choice for automating GUIs. If it is possible for you to use AutoIt instead you have a lot more possibilities there...

Comment: thanks syberdoor, the challenge is, the script is going to be ported to multiple computers where no installation is required. Admin rights to run/install anything is a no no. kindly help.

Comment: An AutoIT script can be compiled so it does not have prerequisites. The main advantage of that language is that in most cases it allows for direct access to a window's controls. Depending on how the program you want to automate looks like your task might be trivial or still a lot of work but at least it is possible. With vbs I know of no way to detect what the gui displays. You would need a com object for your program or it would have to be a userform in excel for you to have some form of control over it imo.

Comment: awesome, thanks a bunch Syberdoor. Lastly, can AutoHotKey be complied so it does not have prerequisites. I'm more familiar with AHK than AutoIT, but if it requires the latter, i will happily switch.

Comment: I never used it but as far as I know it should be possible yes.

Comment: You rock Syberdoor!!! It would have been nice if you entered your comment as an answer so I could have marked it as correct. Thanks again .

Comment: I was unsure whether this would be a good answer as it basically is "it's not possible in vbscript" which was your original question, but I read up on the best practice in such cases, and it seems I should do it anyway so that people have a chance to disagree with me on the topic *g*...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is in general not possible to get such detailed information on a GUI element with VBScript alone.

As you mentioned in your comments that the main reason for choosing VBScript was that you need a solution without prerequisites, I would recommend AutoIt or AutoHotKey instead. Both have exstensive scripting possibilities against guis. 
To prevent the problem of prerequisites you can convert scripts of both of them to executables (it is not a real compilation but rather a package of the script and the interpreter but it has no dependencies)

For AutoHotKey you would use [ahk2exe](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#ahk2exe) to do this, for AutoIt [Aut2Exe](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/compiler.htm)